# Need to show an additional info

Tags: jquery, html, format

I Have a grid and an additional info ( any data).

My HTML

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><a href="#">Show details</a></td>
</tr>
```

So, how can I show the info block? Can I use jQuery for this?

Comment: You can't watch a movie without a ticket! add more info

Comment: Add more info about your info block :)

Comment: Sure you can use jquery. Give the anchor and the block holding the details identifier (id if unique or class if general) and then attach a click even listener on the anchor. when the link is clicked you can then hide/show the details section.

Comment: Please explain your problem so that someone can answer you in a better way. If you have a html element to show when user clicks anchor, just bind the event. +1 for @scrappedcola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show *any* details, you should modify your link as following and add block for details:

```
<td><a id="link" href="javascript:if($('#link').text()=='Show details'){$('#info').css('display','block');$('#link').text('Hide details')}else{$('#info').css('display','none');$('#link').text('Show details')}">Show details</a></td>
<div style="display:none" id="info">There is no additional info for 1 and 2</div>
```

And don't forget to import jquery.